# Error al ejecutar (Esteganografía)

Tags: c++, compilar

Estoy tratando de ejecutar este programa, el cual trata de "ocultar" texto en una imagen .bmp, en visual studio y me salta error de null pointer a la hora de introducir la opción.

```
#pragma warning(disable: 4996)
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <atlimage.h>
#include<iostream>
#include <math.h>
class BMP
{

public:
    BMP();
    ~BMP();
    bool load(const char * fname);  // carga un fichero bmp
    void save(const char * fname);  // almacena el bmp en un fichero bmp
    char * data; // los pixeles del fichero
    int  ancho;
    int  alto;
    int  planosDeColor;
    int  bitsPorPixel;
    char * pixels;
    int  nPixels;
    long  fsize;
};

// obtener un entero a partir de un desplazamiento (offset) en un arreglo de caracteres, la forma en la que lo hace es 
inline int getInt(char * data, int offset)
{
    return 0xff00000000 & (int)(data[offset + 3] << 24) | 0xff0000 & (int)(data[offset + 2] << 16) | 0xff00 & (int)(data[offset + 1] << 8) | 0xff & (int)(data[offset + 0]);
}

// obtener un short (2 bytes) a partir de un desplazamiento (offset) en un arreglo de caracteres

inline int getShort(char * data, int offset)
{
    return 0xff00 & (int)(data[offset + 1] << 8) | 0xff & (int)(data[offset + 0]);
}

//// metodo constructor de la clase
BMP::BMP()
{
    data = NULL;
    ancho = alto = 0;
}

// metodo destructor... liberar la memoria
BMP::~BMP()
{
    if (data)
        delete[] data;
}

// metodo para cargar un archivo
bool BMP::load(const char * fname)
{
    // primero abrimos el fichero para conocer su longitud
    FILE * f = fopen(fname, "rb");
    if (f == NULL)          // el archivo no existe
        return false;
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);  // ir al final del archivo
    fsize = ftell(f);       // en que posicion estamos?
    fclose(f);

    data = new char[fsize]; // reservar memoria para almacenar todo el contenido del fichero

    f = fopen(fname, "rb");
    fread(data, sizeof(char), fsize, f);
    fclose(f);

    int pixelsOffset = getInt(data, 10);
    int headerSize = getInt(data, 14);

    if (headerSize == 40) // BITMAPINFOHEADER
    {
        ancho = getInt(data, 18);
        alto = getInt(data, 22);
        planosDeColor = getShort(data, 26);
        bitsPorPixel = getShort(data, 28);
        pixels = data + pixelsOffset;
    }

    nPixels = ancho * alto;

    return true;
}

// guarda el bitmap en un fichero
void BMP::save(const char * fname)
{
    if (data)
    {
        FILE * f = fopen(fname, "wb");
        fwrite(data, sizeof(char), fsize, f);
        fclose(f);
    }
}

// oculta el texto (str) en el mapa de bits
void ocultar(BMP & bmp, char * str)
{
    int pixelsRequeridos = (1 + strlen(str)) * 8; // calcula el numero de pixels requeridos para almacenar el string
    if (pixelsRequeridos <= bmp.nPixels) // el string cabe en los pixels del bmp
    {
        char * pixel;
        for (pixel = bmp.pixels; *str; str++)
        {
            // descomponer el siguiente caracter en sus bits
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++, *pixel++)
            {
                char bit = ((*str) >> i) & 1; // obtiene el siguiente bit
                if (bit)
                    *pixel |= 1;              // el bit es 1... ponerlo en el pixel actual
                else
                    *pixel &= 0xfe;           // el bit es 0... ponerlo en el pixel actual
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++, *pixel++)  // caracter de fin de string (\0) al final
            *pixel &= 0xfe;
    }
}

// obtiene un string escondido en un bmp y lo retorna en str
void mostrar(BMP & bmp, char * & str)
{
    char * pixel = bmp.pixels;

    // primero contamos cuantos caracteres hay en la imagen
    int n = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        char c = '\0';
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)  // obtener cada bit del caracter
        {
            char bit = ((*pixel) & 1) << i;
            c |= bit;   // concatenar el bit al caracter
            *pixel++;   // siguiente pixel
        }
        n++; // contar un caracter mas
        if (c == '\0') break;  // cuando lleguemos a \0 ya termino el string
    }

    // ahora repetimos el procedimiento anterior, pero esta vez construyendo el string (str)
    pixel = bmp.pixels;
    str = new char[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        str[i] = '\0';
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        {
            char bit = ((*pixel) & 1) << j;
            str[i] |= bit;
            *pixel++;
        }
    }
}

bool modoOcultar = false;
char * archivo1;
char * archivo2;

void imprimirUso(const char * programa)
{
    printf("Uso:\n%s archivo.bmp -ocultar archivo_oculto.bmp\n%s archivo.bmp -mostrar\n", programa, programa);
}
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int opcion;

    do
    {
        printf("\n   1. Ocultar texto");
        printf("\n   2. Mostrar texto");
        printf("\n   3. Salir.");
        printf("\n\n   Introduzca opción (1-3): ");
        cin >> opcion;

        switch (opcion)
        {
        case 1: printf("\n   Introduzca la imagen a modificar: \n");
            cin >> archivo1;
            modoOcultar = true;
            printf("\n   Introduzca nombre de imagen modificada: \n");
            cin >> archivo2;
            break;

        case 2: printf("\n   Introduzca nombre de imagen modificada: \n");
            cin >> archivo1;
            modoOcultar = false;
            break;
        }
    } while (opcion != 3);

    BMP bmp;
    if (!bmp.load(archivo1))  // intentar cargar el archivo
    {
        printf("Imposible abrir %s\n", archivo1);
        return 2;
    }

    if (modoOcultar)
    {
        // leer texto a ocultar:
        char texto[256];
        printf("Escriba el texto a ocultar: ");
        fgets(texto, 255, stdin);
        texto[strlen(texto) - 1] = '\0';  // quitar el caracter \n al final del string
        ocultar(bmp, texto);  // ocultar el texto en el mapa de bits
        bmp.save(archivo2);   // guardar el archivo resultante
    }
    else
    {
        char * buffer;

        mostrar(bmp, buffer);     // obtener el texto almacenado en el bmp
        printf("%s\n", buffer);   // e imprimirlo

        delete[] buffer;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[Imagen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZAXK.jpg)

Comment: Si le das a "Reintentar" te va a parar el código en la línea que falla. Tu fallo es, tal y como dice el error: Accedes a un puntero nulo.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster cuando ejecuto el programa cuando introduzco la opción en el menú me salta el error de la imagen, lo voy a especificar.

Comment: ¿Podrías incluir el número de la línea en la que se produce el error? No veo ninguna imagen. Tienes muchísimas posibilidades de ejecutar código con punteros nulos porque nunca reservas memoria para `char * archivo1, * archivo2`. También haces lo mismo con `char * buffer`.

Comment: "*cuando introduzco la opción en el menú me salta el error de la imagen*" Al introducir ¿Qué opción?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char * archivo1;

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int opcion;

    // ...
    do
    {
        // ...
        switch (opcion)
        {
            case 1: printf("\n   Introduzca la imagen a modificar: \n");
            cin >> archivo1;
```

Como puedes ver, `archivo` es un puntero de tipo `char`... que no apunta a ninguna dirección de memoria válida.

Esto se soluciona modificando la declaración de la variable:

```
char archivo1[200];

int main(// ...
```

Haciendo una reserva de memoria explícita con `new`:

```
char * archivo1;

int main()
{
  archivo1 = new char[200];
  // ...

  delete[] archivo1;
}
```

O, como mejor opción, usando la clase `string`:

```
std::string archivo1;

int main()
{
  cin >> archivo1; // Funciona sin problemas
}
```

Comment: Te has adelantado a mi respuesta :'( allá va mi +1. Le pasa lo mismo con el buffer :) el código no hay por dónde cogerlo x] Hace la definición `char * buffer`, usa el buffer, lo libera (sin haberlo reservado) y en ningún momento mete o copia datos en él :/

Comment: @OscarGarcia y mezcla librerías [tag:c] y [tag:c++], repite `<iostream>`, no inicializa la mayoría de variables...

Comment: @OscarGarcia otras veces me da por explayarme un poco más con otros errores que voy viendo... pero cuando sobrepasan cierto límite me limito a responder sobre lo que se pregunta porque si no veo que la solución al problema planteado inicialmente acaba escondido entre otros tantos detalles